# Why does second terminal tab prompt bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-14.04, gnome-terminal

If I run rails s in the terminal, it works. If I open a new terminal window or tab and run rails c, I get the following error: Run `bundle install` to install missing gems. If I type cd .. and then cd back into the directory and run rails c again, it works.  My question is what would be causing this to occur?

Comment: When you open a new terminal window do you appear in your project directory or your root directory?

Comment: Are you using a ruby version manager?

Comment: @Cyzanfar opening a new terminal opens in the project directory not the root directory.
I am using ruby version manager. So I cd into Desktop/SaaS and run rails s and it spins up the server.  I open a new tab and it automatically positions me at Desktop/SaaS and I run rails c and then get the prompt that I need to run bundle install.  I run cd .. then run cd SaaS and run rails c and it works, no problems.  So merely navigating up one directory and back down one directory fixes the problem.  I would like to not have to do this.  Let me know if I should share more info.

Comment: You might have different configs for you bash so was just waking sure.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing some problems but didn't find the perfect solution.

An alternate working solution for the same is below which worked for me well as expected.

Steps are as below:

> `nano ~/.bash_profile`

Then add the following code at the end of your bash_profile file

> `current_dir=$(pwd)`
>
> `cd $current_dir`

Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: OK that worked for me; now I would like to know why